# How to forward photo with caption to group using telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

I have bot which can takes photo with caption, so I need to forward this whole message to some group, also, this bot can already forward messages with text only, how can I do this with telebot and python?

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for is `Telebot.send_photo(chat_id, photo, caption)`, you can check the documentation [here](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.send_photo).

Comment: But what if I dont know what will be the caption and photo, because this photo will be sent by another user

Comment: When your bot gets an image, check under what variable the photo and the caption are stored, and pass that into the `send_photo()` parameters. 
You can create a handler that takes the information of the message (photo and caption) and then inside the handler you can use `Telebot.send_photo(chat_id, photo=message.photo, caption=message.caption)`.

Comment: To clarify, the handler automatically passes the message object (and therefore message.photo or anything from [this](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) list)

Comment: Oh and sorry, you don't need to check under what variable the photo and the caption are stored since I did that while I was researching to give you the answer. As I stated later in the first message, the variables are message.photo and message.caption.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer:
`@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'text'], func=lambda message: True)`

And also I create check, if message is photo by:

```
    if message.photo:
        photo = message.photo[-1]
        file_id = photo.file_id
        file_info = bot.get_file(file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        bot.send_photo(group_chat_id, downloaded_file, caption=message.caption)
```